# using jquery each method with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display a list of players with a edit button next to each one. When edit is pressed, then the user can edit that player. I'm trying to do this using ajax. The problem: The table will display for a split second then it's a blank screen.

```
<?php foreach($players as $player): ?>   
    <tr>
        <td><?= $player['first_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $player['last_name']; ?></td>
         <td><?= $player['email']; ?></td>
         <td align="center" >
            <form action="" method="post" id="edit_player">
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?= player['user_id']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value='Edit' name='submit'>
            </form>
         </td>             
     </tr> 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Here is my jquery/ajax code. I made some changes from earlier. I think it's better, but it's still not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
var contents = $('#teamMain');
$('.edit_player').each(function(index, value) {

     var formData = $(this).attr('user_id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'views/team_nav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: formData, 
      success: function(data){
         contents.html(data);                     
      }
   });                          
});
});
```

Comment: Id attribute must by uniq, use class attribute if you want mark some group of elements

Comment: Thanks Aleksey, that worked almost too well. For some reason  it won't break out of the loop. Instead, it's constantly reloading the table rows. Out of the frying pan and into the fire! lol

Comment: I note you seem to be replacing the entire contents of the div after each ajax call.

Comment: The piece `$('input[name=user_id]').val()` should be contextualized using `this`, otherwise each ajax call is sending data from the first form only. ... And something does not look right about what you're doing with the `content` variable.

Comment: OK, that's not good. Any way to display the contents all at once? What I mean is, load up #teamMain one time after the values have been caught.

Comment: PeterKA, could you tell me where 'this' is suppose to go? Replace '$' or .val()? Or... $(this).attr('user_id')